# Camel Daemon won't resolve endpoint

Tags: java, xslt, apache-camel

I have a camel context which uses the xslt component.
When I run my routes on my local development machine I don't experience any problems.

But when I deployed my project on a remote server I experience some problems with the xslt component.
I daemonized the project so I can run in the background maybe this is causing a issue?
I checked the path to the xsl files(tested the path found in my log), they are correct I even use absolute paths.

Does anybody have some hints? Or an idea why this is going wrong?

The error log has logged these errors:

```
ERROR:  'Syntax error in '()'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> To[ref:hoo_transformer] <<< in route: Route[[From[jms:incomingHoo]] -> [To[ref:hoo_transformer], T... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: ref://hoo_transformer due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hoo_transformer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://file:/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl due to: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:173)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:114)
    at nl.kabisa.seacon.SwsDeamon.start(SwsDeamon.java:17)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> To[ref:hoo_transformer] <<< in route: Route[[From[jms:incomingHoo]] -> [To[ref:hoo_transformer], T... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: ref://hoo_transformer due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hoo_transformer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://file:/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl due to: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:773)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:610)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1514)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1306)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1213)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1191)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:203)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:101)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: ref://hoo_transformer due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hoo_transformer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://file:/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl due to: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:437)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:394)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:770)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hoo_transformer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://file:/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl due to: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookup(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.component.ref.RefComponent.lookupEndpoint(RefComponent.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.component.ref.RefComponent.createEndpoint(RefComponent.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:419)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hoo_transformer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://file:/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl due to: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry.lookup(ApplicationContextRegistry.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookup(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:54)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://file:/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl due to: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:437)
    at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:843)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.setTransformerSource(XsltBuilder.java:231)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.setTransformerInputStream(XsltBuilder.java:261)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltComponent.createEndpoint(XsltComponent.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:419)
    ... 51 more
Cannot start daemon
Service exit with a return value of 5
```

Comment: A thought: Could it be a filesystem permissions issue? Does the user that camel runs as have perms to read `/var/java/sws/xslt/transform_hoo.xsl`?

Comment: post you answer and mark the question as answered...thx

Comment: @boday I a novice on StackOverflow, I removed my comment and added the answer below

Comment: @Niels, no problem....also make sure you mark it as 'answered' (click the checkmark next to your response)...this clears it from the 'unanswered' list and keeps us all happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I was converting this old camel project to run as daemon.
Because the project was mavenized I believed every lib was fetched remotely .
Apparently the pom also contained a path to a local library, included in the git repo of the project. 
The actual jar missing was the Saxon jar needed for the XSLT component.

So when I ran the project locally I didn't experience any problem because the jar was there. 
But when I build the jar and deployed it the Saxon jar wasn't included.

My solution:

I added an new hosted repository to our Nexus Server and included that dependency into the pom file. So there are no local dependencies anymore.